# Express-validator: How can i use date birthday validator with checkschema?

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, express-validator

I'm developing a project with a form and I need use a validator. I choice express-validator to this job. I am using express-validator with checkschema format and I can't to validate the date. The format date is yyyy/mm/dd. I've tried the code below:

```
`export const validator = {
  editAction: checkSchema({
 
    date: {
        isISO8601: {
            errorMessage: `date of birth is not a valid iso date`
        },
      isBefore: {
        date: '01-01-2008',
        errorMessage: 'should be less than 01-01-2008'
    },
    isAfter: {
        date: '01-01-1920',
        errorMessage: 'should be less than 01-01-1920'
    }
},
  }),
};`
```

I never used this library. Help me please, how can i get the right validator schema?

Comment: Try [validator.js](https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js). I never used `express-validator`,  I think internally they are using `validator.js`.

Comment: https://express-validator.github.io/docs/custom-validators-sanitizers 
Have you gone through this? This might answer your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```js
export const validator = {
    editAction: checkSchema({
        date: {
            custom: {
                options: (value, { req }) => {
                    const dateFormat = /^\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}$/;
                    if (!dateFormat.test(value)) {
                      throw new Error("Invalid date format. Use yyyy/mm/dd");
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    })
};
```

Note that you have to import checkSchema from express-validator first.

Comment: Hello! Thank you my friend!I solved my problem with your suggestion.